# Which ads return more revenue

Tags: google, advertising, google-adsense, blog

i have a blog, i want to display ads and earn money as part time work. Can you suggest me which ads bring up more revenue except Google ads?

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to look into is Ad Affiliate programs for your site.  If you have enough visitors Ad Affiliate companies will pay you to put specific ads on your site.

Google Affiliate Ad programs and you will have a number of companies to look into.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the topic you are blogging about is helpful but,

The best way to find other ad suppliers is to look at other popular sites that blog on your topic. See who they are affiliated with.

Because there are so many ad networks out there I have found this to be the best way. There are just too many places to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Ads depend on:

1. topic relevance
2. position
3. traffic
4. cost

Without a good combination of the factors, you're not going to be making much.  The sticky thing about ads is if you over or under-do any one thing, you're going to suffer.  For example, charge too much and nobody will be buying (not an issue with a network where they tell you what they'll pay)  Charge too little and you'll have no inventory to sell.  If you position the ads way at the bottom or bury the site with ads, forget it, nobody will see them.  Without traffic or content, nobody will show in the first place.  And finally, showing ads about cooking on a car website likely won't get you anywhere either.

So, it's really up to you to built, tweak, repeat until you've got them working right.  It's not as easy as it might seem.